# How can I make the view to be the 1/3 of the screen with using layout_constraintWidth_percent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Here is my custom View,  the width of the my custom View is as much as the width of ImageView and I set ImageView width to be 1/3 of the screen width and maxWidth should be 140dp but it doesn't work

Here is my xml file ,and the problem is that ignores what I have describes as 
percent
`android:maxWidth="144dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".3"`

it takes as much space I have layout_width, layout_height
`android:layout_width="40dp"
 android:layout_height="40dp"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_card_root_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
        tools:text="Title"
        tools:textColor="#000000"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="start"
        tools:text="Sub Title"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        tools:ignore="SpContentDescription"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:maxWidth="144dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:background="@color/gray_70"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLu1Q.png

Comment: Use guideline with percent set to 0.75 and for your view just mark endtostart of this guideline

Comment: It is a cardView and I will use it in carousel (RecyclerView) so I don't want to use guidelines

Comment: what is the view inside cardview?

Comment: I meant not CardView Implementation from Android it is my own Card.Sorry for this confusion

Comment: can you also include images of what you want to achieve and the whole .XML file of the main container or Item Layout.

Comment: @animusmind I have updated, and I have posted the screenshot how it looks like, and I want to have 1/3 of the screen width.

Comment: you should just use `RelativeLayout` & `LinearLayout` inside the `ConstraintLayout` and give all the ratio of width to that one. it works if you are going to use this as ItemView

Comment: Yes it is going to be an item of REcyclerview ,but why I should use RelativeLayout and LinearLayout ?